# Is there any way to convert 'all' strings to uppercase when they are saved

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need convert all strings to uppercase before to write them into the database. Is there any way to tell sql server 2008 to do this automatically? I mean, can sql server 2008 convert my strings to uppercase when  they are saved? Or, do I have to do it programatically?

Comment: For what need?  Would a case insensitive collation work?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: my customer is a little hard and he wants that. I am using a CI collation but that is not what he wants.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you can change your INSERTs and UPDATEs, you'll need a trigger.

Or if you use stored procedures, you can issue UPPER on the parameters.

I'd also consider CHECK constraints with a case sensitive collation to ensure that `UPPER(col) = col` too in case you miss anything, or at least some regular checks

Comment: Yes, it seems. It is not a nice way for me but thank you, now I know there is not any other way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
INSERT INTO <Column NAme> VALUES (Upper('Your Value'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by putting a trigger on the table:

```
create trigger settouppercase
        on mytable
        instead of insert, update
as begin
    delete from mytable where mycolumnid in (select mycolumnid from deleted)

    select mycolumnid, upper(mycolumn) as mycolumn into #upcased from inserted

    insert into mytable(mycolumnid, mycolumn)
    select mycolumnid, mycolumn from #upcased
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ToUpperCase
        ON tblUsers
        AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE  tblUsers
    SET     UserName = UPPER(UserName)
    WHERE   UserId IN (SELECT UserId FROM inserted)

END
```